# Ruby infinite loop causes 100% cpu load

Tags: ruby, curses

I implemented some code, which runs in a loop:

```
loop do
   ..
end
```

In that loop, I handle keypresses with Curses library. If I press N and entered something, I start a new Thread, which counts time( `loop do .. end` again)

The question is, why `loop` or `while true` causes 100% cpu load on one of the cpu cores? Is the problem actaully in loop?

Is there a way to do infinite loop with lower cpu consumption in ruby?

The full sources available [here](https://github.com/Baldrs/track-me)

**UPD - Strace**

```
$ strace -c -p 5480
Process 5480 attached - interrupt to quit
^CProcess 5480 detached
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
51.52    0.002188           0    142842           ioctl
24.21    0.001028           0     71421           select
14.22    0.000604           0     47614           gettimeofday
10.05    0.000427           0     47614           rt_sigaction
0.00    0.000000           0        25           write
0.00    0.000000           0        16           futex
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.004247                309532           total
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it use 100% of the CPU? There is no reason for it not to try - what if this was actually doing some *really important work*? To avoid eating the CPU, ["sleep"](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sleep) the thread. A simple `sleep(0)` suffices.

Comment: There's already `sleep 1` as part of the loop logic inside thread

Comment: There is likely a busy loop somewhere (e.g. in one of the spawned threads) that isn't playing nice ..

Comment: I added `strace` output - could it be Curses.getch in main loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking and suggestions from user2246674 I managed to resolve the issue. It was not inside the threads, it was the main loop.

I had such code inside the main loop:

```
  c = Curses.getch
  unless c.nil? 
     # input handling
```

After adding sleep 1 to `else` problem was resolved. It does nothing when there's no input from Curses, then checks again in one second, and this stops it from actively polling `STDIN` and generating high CPU load