# Ruby TCPServer performance issue

Tags: ruby, multithreading, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

I am encountering an interesting issue with Ruby TCPServer, where once a client connects, it continually uses more and more CPU processing power until it hits 100% and then the entire system starts to bog down and can't process incoming data.

The processing class that is having an issue is designed to be a TCP Client that receives data from an embedded system, processes it, then returns the processed data to be further used (either by other similar data processors, or output to a user).

In this particular case, there is an external piece of code that would like this processed data, but cannot access it from the main parent code (the thing that the original process class is returning it's data to). This external piece may or may not be connected at any point while it is running.

To solve this, I set up a Thread with a TCPServer, and the processing class continually adds to a queue, and the Thread pulls from the queue and sends it to the client.

It works great, except for the performance issues. I am curious if I have something funky going on in my code, or if it's just the nature of this methodology and it will never be performant enough to work.

Thanks in advance for any insight/suggestions with this problem!

Here is my code/setup, with some test helpers:

**process_data.rb**

```
require 'socket'

class ProcessData

  def initialize
    super

    @queue = Queue.new
    @client_active = false

    Thread.new do
      # Waiting for connection
      @server = TCPServer.open('localhost', 5000)

      loop do

        Thread.start(@server.accept) do |client|
          puts 'Client connected'

          # Connection established
          @client_active = true

          begin
            # Continually attempt to send data to client
            loop do

              unless @queue.empty?
                # If data exists, send it to client
                begin
                  until @queue.empty?
                    client.puts(@queue.pop)
                  end
                rescue Errno::EPIPE => error
                  # Client disconnected
                  client.close
                end
              end
              sleep(1)
            end

          rescue IOError => error
            # Client disconnected
            @client_active = false
          end
        end # Thread.start(@server.accept)
      end # loop do
    end # Thread.new do

  end



  def read(data)
    # Data comes in from embedded system on this method

    # Do some processing
    processed_data = data.to_i + 5678 

    # Ready to send data to external client
    if @client_active
      @queue << processed_data
    end

    return processed_data
  end

end
```

**test_embedded_system.rb** (source of the original data)

```
require 'socket'

@data = '1234'*100000 # Simulate lots of data coming ing

embedded_system = TCPServer.open('localhost', 5555)

client_connection = embedded_system.accept
loop do
  client_connection.puts(@data)
  sleep(0.1)
end
```

**parent.rb** (this is what will create/call the ProcessData class)

```
require_relative 'process_data'

processor = ProcessData.new
loop do
  begin
    s = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 5555)
    while data = s.gets
      processor.read(data)
    end
  rescue => e
    sleep(1)
  end
end
```

**random_client.rb** (wants data from ProcessData)

```
require 'socket'

loop do
  begin
    s = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 5000)
    while processed_data = s.gets
      puts processed_data
    end
  rescue => e
    sleep(1)
  end
end
```

To run the test in linux, open 3 terminal windows:

Window 1: ./test_embedded_system.rb

Window 2: ./parent.rb

\CPU usage is stable

Window 3: ./random_client.rb

\CPU usage continually grows

Comment: is what you provided going to reproduce the CPU issue?  Can you share your version of ruby

Comment: Ruby version: ruby 2.3.4p301 (2017-03-30 revision 58214) [x86_64-linux]

Let me see if I can put together a good way to test it, I believe this is the correct code to reproduce the issue, but it's definitely not a trivial setup

Comment: @Anthony I added a test to the question, let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out what the issue was, and unfortunately I lead folks astray with my example.

It turns out my example didn't quite have the issue I was having, and the main difference was the `sleep(1)` was not in my version of process_data.rb.

That sleep is actually incredibly important, because it is inside of a `loop do`, and without the sleep, the Thread won't yield the GVL, and will continually eat up CPU resources.

Essentially, it was unrelated to TCP stuff, and more related to Threads and loops.

If you stumble on this question later on, you can put a `sleep(0)` in your loops if you don't want it to wait, but you want it to yield the GVL.

Check out these answers as well for more info: 
[Ruby infinite loop causes 100% cpu load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258408/ruby-infinite-loop-causes-100-cpu-load#comment25013835_17258408)

[sleep 0 has special meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753094/sleep-0-has-special-meaning)